# Links to website from google redirect to homepage

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I've got some rewrite rules on my server in the httpd-vhost file that take the url and replace /content/site/ with /home/

```
RewriteRule   ^(.+)/$  /content/site/$1.html  [PT,L]

RewriteRule   ^/(\.resources/.*)$  e:/apps/Apache2.2.34/htdocs/$1  [L]

RewriteRule   ^/(home/.+)(\.html)?$  /content/site/$1.html  [PT,L]

RewriteRule   ^/(utilities/.+)(.html)?$  /content/site/$1.html  [PT,L]
```

The problem is when i access my site from google if the link is /content/site/examplepage.html it takes me to my homepage and not the link. This doesn't happen if i copy the link from google and paste it into the url only if i click the link.

Some of the links on google are written as /home/examplepage.html they all work.

Thanks for any help